# implement slide from right menu like facebook app

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller

how to open new view from navigation slider ios. example like in facebook page there is navigation slider and in navigation slider there are profile,message etc.when we click on message and profile then there is new view ,similarly please let me know how to load new view from navigation slider?

Answer (score 2):

From this tutorial:

http://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu

MFSideMenu project utilizes view controller and gives you a simple API demonstration for implementing side-menu functionality like facebook app.

Comment: @RajputNancyKatal in didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can put condition and load view controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good tutorial : http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

The menu slides in from the left, however it should be relatively simple to change this so it enters from the right.